# Why is this ElementRef undefined after navigating away and return back?

Tags: angular

I am having a reference to a `@ViewChild` in one of my components (`favorite-places`) which is the search input field for a Google Maps Autocomplete.

Everything works except when I navigate to another location an return to `favorite-places`.

This is the layout of the component. Note there is a `[couterLink]="['../select']"` which allows me to navigate to another location.

```xml
<div *headerContent fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center"
     style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">    

  <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    <mat-form-field class="form-group">
      <input #search matInput placeholder="Search" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" [formControl]="searchControl">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <button mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['../select']" [queryParams]="{groupId: groupId}" (click)="addPlace()">
    <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
  </button>    
</div>

<div>

  <div class="container">
    <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom" style="height:150px; margin-top: 15px;">
      <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>PlaceID: {{selectedPlace?.place_id}}</span><br/>
    <span>Name: {{selectedPlace?.name}}</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

As I said, everything works except when I enter the place, leave it and then return to it. In this case I'll see this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at favorite-places.component.ts:61
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4062)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:872
    ...
```

This is where the error occurs:

```js
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
    let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, 
      { types: ['establishment'] });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        // ..
      });
    });
  }
);
```

```js
export class FavoritePlacesComponent implements OnInit {

  // ..

  @ViewChild("search")
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;

}
```

It would seem that `this.searchElementRef` gets nullified or undefined after leaving the location. Going back to it does however not re-create it. This looks like a lifecycle problem to me but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Are you accessing nativeElement inside ngAfterViewInit()?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Nope. I am not implementing this function at this point.

Comment: You can access viewchild element properties only when DOM is rendered on the screen. So please add inside  ngAfterViewInit() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose usage of `nativeElement` in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

Reason why your code works for the first time is that `load()` is asynchronous and your callback is invoked in next VM turn with component already rendered. BUT after returning to the same route Maps API is already loaded so promise returned from `load()` resolves synchronously - before `ngAfterViewInit`.

It's debatable if load should be always asynchronous to remove ambiguity.

Comment: I have tried this but it does not solve the issue unfortunately. I've posted an answer myself. It seems to be connected to the fact that I am replacing the header during navigation events which seems to destroy the reference and it seems that for some reason it is not getting re-created (no idea why though).

Answer (score 0):

Once again I ran into the trap of my replaceable header.

Note that I am using a `HeaderContentDirective` which tears down the header and re-creates it on each navigation event.

```xml
<div *headerContent ..>
    <!-- .. -->
</div>
```

..

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[headerContent]',
})
export class HeaderContentDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private headerContent: HeaderContentService, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.headerContent.setContents(this.templateRef);
  }
}
```

and further in my `ApplicationComponent`

```js
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this
      .headerContentService
      .contents
      .subscribe(ref => {
        setTimeout(() => {

          if (this.currentHeaderView !== null) {
            this.logger.trace('Destroying currentHeaderView header ..');
            this.currentHeaderView.destroy();
            this.currentHeaderView = null;
          }
          if (ref === null) {
            this.logger.trace('No new header reference ..');
            return;
          }
          this.logger.trace('Creating embedded view ..');
          this.currentHeaderView = this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(ref);
        });
      });
  }
```

It would seem that this won't allow me to do what I want here which also means I'll have to move the autocomplete input to somewhere else or find another workaround.

Comment: Try to enclose mat-form-field in own component with `ngAfterViewInit` and maps loader

Comment: I don't understand Angular rendering completely but I think this whole design is prone to subtle bugs steming from component tree traversal order, etc.

Comment: @TomaszBłachut I might give it a try but for now I just want to make progress with implementing the main features of my application. I'll try to optimize this a little later on if necessary. Thanks for your help though!